# Sed substitute pattern within a line

Tags: regex, awk, sed

How can I substitute characters only within a specific pattern, preferably in sed but awk or otherwise if there's an easier option? I would like to replace spaces in my html h3 ids with hyphens (-), but I don't want it to hyphen the entire line.

Eg, in my foo.html:

```
<p>This is a paragraph which likes its spaces.</p>

<h3 id="No spaces in this id please">Keep spaces in this title</h3>

<p>Here's another paragraph with spaces.</p>

<h3 id="Another id that should be spaceless">Spaces please!</h3>

<p>Yes I would like extra noodles in my soup.</p>
```

What I want are h3s like this:

```
<h3 id="Another-id-that-should-be-spaceless">Spaces please!</h3>
```

I've tried

```
sed -e "/^<h3 id=\"/,/\">/s/ /-/g;" <foo.html >bar.html
```

But this greedily adds hyphens to lines (2nd p) and parts (h3 content) which shouldn't have hyphens! Bar.html:

```
<p>This is a paragraph which likes its spaces.</p>

<h3-id="No-spaces-in-this-id-please">Keep-spaces-in-this-title</h3>

<p>Here's-another-paragraph-with-spaces.</p>

<h3-id="Another-id-that-should-be-spaceless">Spaces-please!</h3>

<p>Yes I would like extra noodles in my soup.</p>
```

Note I'm using GNU sed. Thanks!

Comment: Do you only  need this, for line 4?

Comment: No, for the whole file. SLePort's answer does that. Thanks k-five.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sed replace one space at a time in the `id` value of `h3` tags. When substitution succeeds, the `t` command loops to `:a` label to search for  remaining spaces to replace:

```
sed -e ':a;s/\(<h3[^>]*id="[^"> ]*\) \(.*\)/\1-\2/;ta;' < foo.html > bar.html
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great! I don't think i grok what the t and a are doing though.

Comment: You're welcome... I updated the command to restrict the replacements to `id` values.

Comment: Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).